# lvalue required as left operand of assignment (incrementing a referenced variable) C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, pass-by-reference, lvalue

Say I have a variable in main, we'll call it var.
I have a function that I want to be able to increment var within it.

```
function (int &var)
{
    //Body
    &var += 1;
}
```

I get the error:

lvalue required as left operand of assignment. 
How can I fix this?

EDIT:

```
//In header file:
void addActivities(struct activity activityEntry[], int &activityIndex, int 
&activityList);

//In Main:
struct activity activityEntry[LIST_SIZE];
int activityIndex = 0;
int activityList = 0;
//unrelated code...
case 1: addActivities(&activityEntry[activityIndex], activityIndex, 
activityList);

//In actual function:
void addActivities(struct activity activityEntry[], int *activityIndex, int 
&activityList)
{
    //unrelated code...
    activityList += 1;
}
```

Then the error:

Program3Main.cpp:(.text+0x12b): undefined reference to `addActivities(activity*, int&, int&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Just use `var += 1;` I am wondering whether I should vote to close for typo.

Comment: When I remove the &, it tells me undefined reference to function(var)

Comment: It's hard to suggest what to do without a [mcve].

Comment: It looks like the function definition for `addActivities()` takes three arguments: an array of structs, a pointer to int, and then an int (as a reference). You appear to be passing it an array of structs, an int, and another int. That's assuming that the error arises from your call directly underneath `//unrelated code...`.

Comment: When I change the referenced int to int& in the argument, it tells me: invalid conversion from int* to int. Which part of it should be changed to make it match? (For the referenced int?)

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of the rest of the code is, but if the function expects an int, give it an int. When you call the function and pass in &var, you're actually passing the *address* of `var`, hence the error about trying to convert an `int*` (which is the *address* of an `int`) to an `int`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I appreciate it. I haven't solved my issue, but I feel like I'm going to need someone to look in depth into the whole thing to figure this out, so I'll ask a friend to look at it in person.

Comment: @HannahLouise Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `&` from in front of `var` inside your function:

```
function (int &var)
{
    //Body
    var += 1;
}
```

The `&` inside the function acts as an address operator, which means that you're actually incrementing the *address* of `var` and not the value it points to.

Another way of phrasing: using `&` as a parameter (as you did with `function(int &var)`) means that you're actually passing in `var` itself, rather than it's value. So when you increment `var` inside the function, you no longer need a reference to it, because the `var` inside function is the same `var` that was passed into `function()` (from within `main()`, for example).

And don't forget a return type for your function. You can also increment `var` using the increment operator, like so:

```
#include <iostream>

void increment(int &var)
{
    var++;
}

int main() {
  int num = 0;
  increment(num);
  increment(num);
  std::cout << num << std::endl; // prints 2
}
```

Comment: There wasn't a return type because it's not a real function, I just made it like this for simplicity's sake. When I take away the &, it tells me undefined reference to this variable...

Comment: @HannahLouise I figured. Just making sure.

Comment: @HannahLouise Can you post the full example that gives you that error?

Comment: The whole thing is monstrous, but I tried to post the related bits